# How to create View for 30+ days after column date

Tags: list-view, date

I have two columns, a site complete column and a report complete column. I need a view to show all blanks in the report complete column if today is 30+ days past the site complete date. Everything I find on this uses [Today] to calculate, however that does not seem like it will work for what I am doing.

I tried [site complete]+30, and that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 6):

In views, the `[Today]` column will work as a filter.

In your view you would have a compound filter:

```
Report Complete is equal to and leave the field blank.

And

Site Complete is greater than or equal to [Today]-30
```

This is looking for blank report complete fields with the additional filter that the site complete is more than 30 days ago. Is that what you want?

Comment: But.. enter those formulas **without spaces**  ``[Today] - 30``  will fail ``[Today]-30`` is fine

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman thanks, updated, should have known better

Comment: That is what I want, it just did not seem like it was what I needed it to be. Thank you

Comment: Great, if this solves your problem, be sure to tick the check box to mark it as an answer. Welcome to sp.se!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above, but it didnt work.  "Greater" didn't seem to function as expected.
When I altered it to the following, then it worked fine...

SITECOMPLETE is less than or equal to [TODAY]-30

Hmmmm, nevermind, my needs were to see if the date itself was more than 365 days old, which sounds like its slightly different than what was requested by the original poster.  (I can't delete my entry, so I just amended it).